# Apigee - Api Portal: deployed environments have vanished

Tags: apigee

Since a few days ago, my Apigee Api Portal is showing this error:

```
No server entry found with ID 9acb068f-906b-4e97-88ae-f3f25d00abfa
```

I also noticed my deployed environments (*test, prod*) have disappeared, but oddly enough the API URL associated to those environment are still active and working as expected. So I believe is an interface error: interface shows no deployed environment, but besides that, all works perfectly.

Any try to re-deploy the environment produce an "Operation failed" error.

http://status.apigee.com/ doesn't show any problem.

Any clue about what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please let us know your 'organization' name to isolate the issue? You can email help@apigee.com with details about your org.

Thanks,
Archendra